# MSMTP Gmail, username and password incorrect

Tags: server, email, gmail

I am trying to send emails using the php `mail();` function. I have installed msmtp to allow me to use a gmail account. However whenever I try to send test email using `msmtp` then a destination email, the system freezed and I cannot write more commands.

This is the contents of `~/.msmtprc`:

```
account gmail
tls on
tls_starttls on
tls_certcheck off
auth on
logfile ~/.msmtp.log
host smtp.gmail.com
port 587
user ****@gmail.com
from ****@gmail.com
password **********

account default : gmail
```

Also when it does sometimes work, I get an error which says bad credentials even though the details are correct, access for less secure apps is on and there is no 2-step verification.

Comment: Generate `Google App Password` . That's how I managed to use it

Comment: When I go to: [here](https://security.google.com/settings/security/apppasswords) I get a message saying it is not available for my account. Is it because I'm not using two step verification?

Comment: I'm already using that for security purposes, it might have an affect. Before 2FA, I used to enable a setting to allow use of less secure apps. Not sure if it's still there.

Comment: It is and I already a have enabled it. I wrote this all down below the contents of `~/.msmtprc`

Comment: [As per this article](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7126229?visit_id=1-636129170523342401-3866201836&hl=en&rd=1) There are two ways, one is allowing less secure app, which you did, other is to use 2FA. And [here](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255) it is mentioned that, [although you might have enabled less secure option, password can still fail.](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6009563)

Answer (score 0):

If allowing less secure app doesn't work, you should consider 2FA.

Here is my working configuration:

```
account default
host smtp.gmail.com          
port 587                     
from "yourusername@gmail.com"   
tls on                       
tls_starttls on              
tls_trust_file /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
auth on                     
user "yourusername"       
password "yourapppassword"       
logfile ~/.msmtp.log
```

Comment: Sadly not, still get the same error message:

Comment: `msmtp: authentication failed (method PLAIN)
msmtp: server message: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
msmtp: server message: 535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials j189sm15214899wmd.22 - gsmtp
msmtp: could not send mail (account default from /root/.msmtprc)
`